# How to make a realtime rollingwindow graph using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, graph, real-time, mpandroidchart

*[also posted on [MPAndroidChart's Github]](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/314)*

I need realtime graph with a rolling windows, that's when I ran into 'problems'. Adding data is no problem, but after adding data with an Xvalue(index) that's higher than the current width of the graph the graph doesn't autoscroll because it don't seem to be able to always display [X] Xvalues.

Example of issue:
[image]
The result in graph [3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8zd5f64i4etrxk/rolling_window_graph_example.mp4?dl=0) is not what I want for displaying realtime data. A scrollingwindow is much more usefull. So I tried to archieve this..

My working 'solution' was to remove the first Xvalue, add a new one and move all Xindexes of all Entries on screen one to the left. The result is some code like this:

```
int GRAPH_WIDTH = 10;
LineData lineData = chart.getData();
LineDataSet lineDataSet = lineData.getDataSetByIndex(0);                        
int count = lineDataSet.getEntryCount();

// Make rolling window
if (lineData.getXValCount() <= count) {
    // Remove/Add XVal
    lineData.getXVals().add("" + count);
    lineData.getXVals().remove(0);

    // Move all entries 1 to the left..
    for (int i=0; i < count; i++) {
        Entry e = lineDataSet.getEntryForXIndex(i);
        if (e==null) continue;

        e.setXIndex(e.getXIndex() - 1);
    }

    // Set correct index to add value
    count = GRAPH_WIDTH; 
}

// Add new value
lineData.addEntry(new Entry([random value], count), 0);

// Make sure to draw
chart.notifyDataSetChanged();
chart.invalidate();
```

This works quite well actually (as seen in [this video here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8zd5f64i4etrxk/rolling_window_graph_example.mp4?dl=0) ), but I feel like there must be an easier way to do this. Maybe I overlooked some API window/scrolling.. 
But if this is the 'right' way to archieve this result then it would be an enhancement to add support for this kind of graphs in your library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the video.
I am surprised you found a workaround that is rather complicated but works quite well.

Unfortunately this is **currently the only way** to achieve what you want. I will work on making this easier soon probably reusing some of your code.

Also take a look at these two methods:

`setScaleMinima(...)`
`centerViewPort(...)`

Comment: Unfortunately, but thanks for answering and looking into it in the future!

I also tried playing with the two methods you mention, but didn't come to a working solution.

Comment: Please keep in mind that scrolling back to view old data is also interesting when implementing something like this. My workaround doesn't have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and changed it a bit. It will only show up to GRAPH_WIDTH number of points at a time. Then it scrolls along deleting the older data. Useful if you're only interested in relatively recent data. Is that what you were going for?

```
public void addTimeEntry() {

    String entry_date_time = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d - HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
    LineData lineData = mChart.getData();
    int GRAPH_WIDTH = 15;

    if (lineData != null) {

        LineDataSet set = lineData.getDataSetByIndex(0);

        if (set == null) {
            set = createSet();
            lineData.addDataSet(set);
        }

        // Make rolling window
        if (lineData.getXValCount() > GRAPH_WIDTH) {
            lineData.getXVals().remove(0);
            set.removeEntry(0);

            lineData.getXVals().add(entry_date_time);
            lineData.addEntry(new Entry((float) (Math.random() * 40) + 30f, GRAPH_WIDTH), 0);

           // lineData.getXVals().add(entry_date_time);
            // Move all entries 1 to the left..
            for (int i=0; i < set.getEntryCount(); i++) {
                Entry e = set.getEntryForXIndex(i);
                if (e==null) continue;

                e.setXIndex(e.getXIndex() - 1);
            }
        }
        else{
            lineData.getXVals().add(entry_date_time);
            lineData.addEntry(new Entry((float) (Math.random() * 40) + 30f, lineData.getXValCount()-1), 0);
        }

        // let the chart know it's data has changed
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mChart.invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou robert, but the code i provided was some sample code and my solution was already working ( [as seen here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k8zd5f64i4etrxk/rolling_window_graph_example.mp4?dl=0) ). My question was about a better way to archieve a rolling window. Please see @philipp-jahoda 's answes on his GitHub: [Issue 314](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/314) and [Issue 431](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/431) . Thanks for your code anyway!